# Convert this Responsive Blog Card Slider made using HTML, CSS and Swiper js into React js with Swiper js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm new to react and I'm trying to use this blog slider https://codepen.io/JavaScriptJunkie/pen/WgRBxw?editors=1100 in my react project.

I convert HTML into jsx and add style to it but i don't know how to use javascript code in my react file , it is using Swiper js but i'm not able to do this in my react code.
I read the swiperjs react documentation but not able to do.

**This is the Javascript code**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.blog-slider', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: 'fade',
      loop: true,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
      },
      // autoHeight: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.blog-slider__pagination',
        clickable: true,
      }
    });
```

**Please help me how to use this swiper js code in my react project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good idea but try using `useEffect` hook for executing code on the client-side.
Here's how I did it. I included the SwiperJs required files in the head of the `index.html` file in the public directory of the react app.

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then in `App.js` used the following code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.innerHTML = `
    var swiper = new Swiper(".blog-slider", {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: "fade",
      loop: true,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
      },
      // autoHeight: true,
      pagination: {
        el: ".blog-slider__pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
    })`
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }, [])
```

This is what `App.js` after this looks like and it works the same way as in codepen.

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.innerHTML = `
    var swiper = new Swiper(".blog-slider", {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: "fade",
      loop: true,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
      },
      // autoHeight: true,
      pagination: {
        el: ".blog-slider__pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
    })`
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="blog-slider">
        <div className="blog-slider__wrp swiper-wrapper">
          <div className="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
            <div className="blog-slider__img">
              <img
                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/muhammederdem/image/upload/v1535759872/kuldar-kalvik-799168-unsplash.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
            <div className="blog-slider__content">
              <span className="blog-slider__code">26 December 2019</span>
              <div className="blog-slider__title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</div>
              <div className="blog-slider__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Recusandae voluptate repellendus magni illo ea animi?{" "}
              </div>
              <a href="#" className="blog-slider__button">
                READ MORE
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
            <div className="blog-slider__img">
              <img
                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/muhammederdem/image/upload/v1535759871/jason-leung-798979-unsplash.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
            <div className="blog-slider__content">
              <span className="blog-slider__code">26 December 2019</span>
              <div className="blog-slider__title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor2</div>
              <div className="blog-slider__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Recusandae voluptate repellendus magni illo ea animi?
              </div>
              <a href="#" className="blog-slider__button">
                READ MORE
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
            <div className="blog-slider__img">
              <img
                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/muhammederdem/image/upload/v1535759871/alessandro-capuzzi-799180-unsplash.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
            <div className="blog-slider__content">
              <span className="blog-slider__code">26 December 2019</span>
              <div className="blog-slider__title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</div>
              <div className="blog-slider__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Recusandae voluptate repellendus magni illo ea animi?
              </div>
              <a href="#" className="blog-slider__button">
                READ MORE
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="blog-slider__pagination"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```